# what happens if ufw firewall is inactive?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I want to know more of what ufw is. I'll ask some questions and you can let me know if i'm right or not.

1. ufw helps us to block connections or allow connections from specific ip address or whatever. I'm curious what happens if ufw is not enabled which means it's INACTIVE. does it mean it allows anything at all? whatever we want?
2. let's say I enabled ufw, add one rule. if the answer to previous question was (IT ALLOWS ANYTHING If it's inactive) , then if I only have one rule and ufw is active, it means anything else(any kind of my service that listens on some port) is blocked by default and I have to enable it to allow it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes to your first answer, it inactive so all traffic goes through. Then See this excerpt:

> By default, UFW is set to deny all incoming connections and allow all outgoing connections. This means anyone trying to reach your cloud server would not be able to connect, while any application within the server would be able to reach the outside world.

So to answer your question: "That rule will be obeyed or honoured". Let's say the rule is set to allow a particular connection, then based on the default `ufw` rule to `deny` incoming connections, only that connection will go through... This `ufw` default settings is most useful for limiting access on a "need to" basis.

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: so, If ufw is INACTIVE, it means it doesn't allow any connections from outside the world. then why does it let me login with ssh? ssh needs 22 port which is not activated because firewall is INACTIVE

Comment: You got me wrong it does allow, remember it's not active so not blocking traffic!

Comment: i get it. I read this "By default, UFW is set to deny all incoming connections and allow all outgoing connections". but it turns out by default ufw is set to ALLOW because it's inactive

Comment: Yes when inactive that is the case but if you switch it on then the other case applies!

Comment: what if I told you that my firewall is inactive, yet still blocks some traffic, and I had to run again `sudo ufw disable` to see the traffic going though!

Answer (score 0):

UFW inactive means firewall is off. that means connection from everywhere  is possible.